# composite key and foreign keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, entity

I am developing asp.net MVC3 application and I have following entity

This entity has composite key (CreditRegistryId  and Accoubnt No are primary keys). CreditRegistryId   is a foreign key as well. How can I make composite key and foreign key. I am using DbContext API from EF 4.1. I am not using edmx ( ORM designer)

```
[Table("tbaAccount")]
    public class Account
    {

       [Column(Name="Creditor Registry ID")]  // PK FK
       public int CreditRegistryId {get;set;}


       [Column(Name = "[Account No]")]        //PK
       public int AccountNo { get; set; }

       [Column(Name = "[Date Opened]")]
       public DateTime DateOpened { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey("tblAccountStatus")]
       [Required]
       [Column(Name = "Account Status ID")]  // FK
       public int AccountStatusId { get; set; }

       [Required]
       [Column(Name = "Date First Reported")]
       public DateTime DateFirstReported { get; set; }

       [Required]
       [Column(Name = "Credit Limit")]
       public double CreditLimit { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public double Balance { get; set; }
}
```

and other entity lets say is

```
public class CreditRegistry
        {
public int CreditRegistryId  {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF does not support associations that use only one property of the ones that participate in a composite key.
Not sure if this scenario can be implemented.